# Launch (and install) android application from android browser

Tags: android, browser

I want to add button to our mobile web application, which allows user to launch our android application.

As I dont know if application is already installed on device, I need:

- if application is not installed install application at first
- launch application

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force an install upon a user.

The closest you can get is to have an activity in your application have an `<intent-filter>` that maps to a URL on your Web site:

```
    <activity android:name="URLHandler"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="commonsware.com"
                android:path="/whatever"
          />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then, on your Web app, have a link to that URL. When the user clicks the link, on devices that have your app installed, your designated activity will open. On devices that do not have your app installed, the user will be taken to your designated Web page, where you can prompt them with instructions on how to download and install your app.

Answer (score -2):

if (v.getId() == R.id.ImageButton01) {

```
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {


             Toast.makeText(this, "Application Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent();

            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            i.setClassName("com.xxx.your_package_name",
                    "com.xxx.your_class_name");

            startActivity(i);

        }
    }
```

try {

```
startActivity(intent);
```

}

catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(OpenPdf.this,

```
    "No Application Available to View PDF",

    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

//connect to given path for downloadinng
//use activitynot found exception  to catch if not installed and  give user the path of //your downloadable file some thing l
}

Comment: I understand mobile web application as web page not Java App.

Comment: @ maciek  you wanna  search wather that  apllication is already installed or not without  refering to your application package and activity name you canot find that weather it is alreday there or not .either you are making web applicatiuon or android application ultimatley  your app is in android which you wanted to make it installed on android device .